# How to use local paths to repositories on hard disk in hgrc?

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg, msys2

I have repository on local machine `C:\repo\my_proj`

I want add path to my repository for using in `TortoiseHG Workbanch`

If I type my configurations in file `<work_place>\.hg\hgrc`

```
[paths]
C:\repo\my_proj
```

application is sending an error message:

> No valid *default* remote repositary URL or path has been configured for this repository.
>
> Please type and save a remote repository path on the Sync widget

But all works when I use terminal GIT-BASH on my OS

```sh
hg pull /c/repo/my_proj/
```

How to use right syntax for adding paths to local repositories in `hgrc`?

**About software:**

Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.9)

Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Sample syntax for use on Windows:

```
[paths]
file:///c:/repo/my_proj/
```

or

```
[paths]
repo = file:///c:/repo/my_proj/
```

**UPD:**

or

```
[paths]
default = S:\repo\my_proj
```